# The arrows $u,v$ in the pushout of $f,g$ in $\text{Grp}$ are monic if $f,g$ are monic.

Tags: category-theory

From Mac Lane's Category Theory:

> The arrows $u,v$ in the pushout of $f,g$ in $\text{Grp}$ are monic if $f,g$ are monic.

Let $f:G \rightarrow G',g : G \rightarrow G'', u: G' \rightarrow G' \coprod_G G'', v : G'' \rightarrow G' \coprod_G G''$.

I can see that I would have to show that $uh=uh' \Rightarrow h = h'$ for $h,h' : H \rightarrow G'$, but I'm having trouble finding a way to show this.

Anyone have any ideas?